# How to color text in private message in mIRC

Tags: irc, mirc

am tring to input my each text line in private message colored,  i use this code it is showing colored text but adding a space before text. how can i remove that space

```
on *:INPUT:?:{
  say 4 $strip($1-)
  halt
}
```

and also now commands like

```
/clear
```

is not working .. showing in read but its not working

Answer (score 0):

on input events are sensible
if you dont know how it works, dont mess with it, since it may mess with all your scripts

try this

```
on *:input:?:{
if (!$inpaste) && (!$ctrlenter) && ($left($1,1) != /) {
command here
haltdef
}
}
```

by the way, this event must be on top of all on input events to work